# How to pass result from Observable properly to service?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to pass data to my Modal. But data are from API so I need to fetch them first.

```
OpenModal(): void {
    let teams;
    this.teams$.subscribe(result => teams = result);

    const modal = this.modalService.showDialog({
        userId: this.userId,
        teams: teams
    });

    // Listen to Close Modal event
    modal.close.subscribe((result) => {
        if (result) {
            this.doSomething();
        }
    });
}
```

This working fine but I feel in my bones that is not done well.

First of all I took off data out of the stream `teams$` and assigned to variable. I think it's wrong but I cannot figure out how to make it fully reactive without nested subscriptions like below:

```
OpenModal(): void {
    this.teams$.subscribe(teams => {
        const modal = this.modalService.showDialog({
            userId: this.userId,
            teams: teams
        });

        // Listen to Close Modal event
        modal.close.subscribe((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.doSomething();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Any idea how can I do it better?

Comment: Why you cant nested subscriptions? you can use async/await also

Comment: Nesting subscriptions is a bad practice.

Comment: Have you try using subject ?

Comment: I know what is subject, but not sure how it could help in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very easy solution, don't why I didn't come up on this before

```
OpenModal(): void {
 this.teams$.pipe(
    map(teams => {
       return this.modalService.showDialog({
        userId: this.userId,
        teams: teams
       });
    }),
    switchMap(modal => modal.close)        
    )
    .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result) {
            this.doSomething();
        }
    });
}
```